# How to define return type for typescript class

Tags: typescript

Is it possible somehow to set custom return type **implicitly** for class?
For example:

```
class A { }
class B {
    constructor() {
        const a = new A();
        return a;
    }
}
const a = new B(); // here I need `a` to be type of A in typescript, but it is B
console.log(a instanceof A); // => true
```

I tried:

```
class B {
    constructor() {
        const a = new A();
        return a as A;
        // return a as any as A;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not supported https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11588#issuecomment-253602163. Why would you do this?

Comment: @AlekseyL.
Class adds some new methods dynamically (mixin) depending on what passed to constructor.